# Flowfiles are stuck in queue while calling store procedure using Execute Script

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE553.png)

I am trying to call store procedure using groovy script and the processor I am using is Execute Script (using groovy because i want to capture the response of store procedure).
But the flow files are getting stuck and when I am restarting the processor it's getting passed
The same code I am using on other environment it's working fine without an issue.

Below is code I am using to call the store procedure:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.*
import groovy.sql.OutParameter
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.Clob

try{
def lookup = context.controllerServiceLookup
def dbServiceName = ConncationPool.value
def dbcpServiceId = lookup.getControllerServiceIdentifiers(ControllerService).find {
cs -> lookup.getControllerServiceName(cs) == dbServiceName
}

def conn = lookup.getControllerService(dbcpServiceId).getConnection();
sql = Sql.newInstance(conn);
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
attr1= flowFile.getAttribute('attr1')
attr2= flowFile.getAttribute('attr2')
attr3= flowFile.getAttribute('attr3')
def data = []

String sqlString ="""{call procedure_name(?,?,?,?)}""";

def OUT_JSON

def parametersList = [attr1,attr2,attr3,Sql.VARCHAR];


sql.call(sqlString, parametersList) {out_json_response ->
OUT_JSON = out_json_response
};

def attrMap = ['out_json_response':String.valueOf(OUT_JSON),'Conn':String.valueOf(conn)]
flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attrMap)
conn.close()
sql.close();
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
catch (e){
if (conn != null) conn.close();
if (sql != null) sql.close();
log.error('Scripting error', e)
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "error", e.getMessage())
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
} finally {
if (conn != null) conn.close();
if (sql != null) sql.close();
}
```

Can you please help me to solve the issue. Is anyone face the same issue?

Comment: Hi, if possible can you upload screenshots of the processor run schedule? There might be some issue with it if it's running after stop and start of the processor.

Comment: Done can you please check. and also the threads are getting pass after some time for example 15mins after without doing any restarting the processor

Comment: @Vectors, Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the run schedule in your screenshot.
So first go to the configuration by right clicking on the processor.

[image]

There you'll find a tab named *Scheduling*. Click on it.

[image]

Now, check if the *Scheduling Strategy* is marked as CRON driven or Timer driven.
There you can also check the *Run Schedule*.

When you mentioned that your script runs after restarting or every 15 minutes, I thought that your *Run Schedule* is set to run every ~15 minutes.

Just verify that and if that is the case, stop the processor and change the below configuration to:

Scheduling Strategy: Timer Driven

Run Schedule: 0 sec

[image]

**NOTE: Before making any changes, if the initial flow was not developed by you, check if changing the *Scheduling* of the processor will not have any undesired effect. Or just make sure why it was set to run every 15 minutes.**

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information but the thing is my processor is scheduled to run on 0 sec, as soon as the file comes it should trigger the ExecuteScript Processor but instead the flow files are getting stuck there

Comment: Can you check if the processor is getting triggered or not? If the processor is getting triggered you'll see the a small icon on the top right of the processor where you can see if the processor is in use. I still think it is the issue with nifi and not the script, also check the configuration of the incoming connection to the execute script where the flowfiles are stuck.

Comment: what could be the reason, i check everything. it's working fine for one environment but other its not. and all the configurations are same

Comment: Hi @Techie , I can't think about any specific reason. All I can say is, if your script is working fine on other environments and also after restarting the processor, then the script doesn't have any issue. Try to focus more on the NiFi part